# Is it acceptable to edit someone else's question which entirely changes the original question OR ask a question that may be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

Is it acceptable to modify a question (adding details and conditions to obtain the situation) which seems similar to the problem one encounter rather than creating a new question which might be marked as duplicate?
**As I encountered the same situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967212/compilation-failure-for-spring-boot-application-with-java-9-and-maven) but my working environment is different (system and versions) and I have applied all solutions provided to this question but that didn't help.**

Should I post a new question or modify by adding details of my environment?

**Can I ask a question by commenting on that post?**

**If I ask the question how can it be different, as I asked this question is getting down votes yet it is different from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20042/if-you-are-not-satisfied-with-answers-on-someone-elses-question-should-you-ask)?**

Comment: “Can I ask a question by commenting on that post?” - You should absolutely not do this.  Questions submitted as a comment will be deleted.  Commentary submitted as an answer will be deleted.  If you have a question it, but if you know of an existing question, explain how your question is different

Comment: If the answer is not the same, the question is not the same. Ask a new question. (although also say "I have read question ABC, because my environment is different step X gives error DEF")

Comment: I upvoted this question to protect @Pooja infront of creepy downvote flooding, and to compensate reputation loss for 2,5 downvotes. Despite I do not agree on him, he is a newbie.

Comment: @neverMind9 Upvotes aren't meant to _compensate downvotes_. And voting at Meta is different anyways.

Comment: @neverMind9 please don't distort voting in such a manner.  'he is a newbie' - and you know this.. how?

Comment: Also @neverMind9, do not assume gender please. The OP is female.

Comment: ^^^ cc: @MartinJames

Comment: @Unitato Sorry, did not know that Pooja is female. But how do you know?

Comment: @neverMind9 Pooja is a Hindu female name, common in India, where I live. (I'm a Hindu myself)

Comment: @Unitato I see. I thought it of as a nickname.

Comment: @Unitato what?  I the only gender-relevant word in my comment was in a quote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any edit to a question should respect the intent of the person posting the question - using edits to get around the 'risk' of a duplicate vote or downvotes is... not cool.

Back when I used to post much more comments than I do now, the standard line I'd use was "You should ask a question *referencing this question*, but including what differentiates your current situation".

So - yes, you should ask a new question. Make it clear that you've read possible duplicates, tried the answers and they didn't work, and make the differences in the environment clear.

Comment: *“using edits to get around the 'risk' of a duplicate vote or downvotes is... not cool.”* - I agree. However, getting downvoted is also not cool for people with low reputation, because then they end up at the 40-Minute-restriction for questions.

Answer (score 14):

No, editing the original question to fit your needs isn't acceptable in any way.

If you have a similar question about a problem, but different problems conveyed  by your particular environment or context, ask a new question, and maybe refer to that original one with it to clearly indicate your question isn't a duplicate.